# Remove Google Cardboard "place phone into your cardboard viewer" message

Tags: google-cardboard

I have a Cardboard app which has multiple activities, but every time I start one of the activities it displays the "place phone into your cardboard viewer" message, how do you stop these messages from being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You must call: `setDisplayMode` and `setTransitionViewEnabled`.

Set `setTransitionViewEnabled` as `false`.

Use like this:

```
vrVideoView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);
vrVideoView.setTransitionViewEnabled(false);
```

I have used it and its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove the dialog , settings and close button in cardboard View

```
 try {
           var f = VrWidgetView::class.java.getDeclaredField("vrUiLayer");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            var vrLayer =  f.get(mVrVideoView) as UiLayer

            // - here you can directly access to the UiLayer class - //


            // to hide the up-right settings button
            vrLayer.setSettingsButtonEnabled(false);

            //setting listener to null hides the x button
            vrLayer.setBackButtonListener(null);

            // these visibility options are frequently updated when you play videos,
            // so you have to call them often


            // OR


            vrLayer.setEnabled(false); // <- just hide the UI layer


        } catch ( e:Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```